# How can I add a sub-query to this cursor?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, cursor

I tried to add a sub query (StoCount) to the following cursor:

```
        DECLARE trans_cur CURSOR FOR
        SELECT b.TransportNumber, 
            SUM(CASE WHEN a.DeliveryItemStatus = 'C' OR a.DeliveryItemStatus = 'V' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Completed, 
            COUNT(*) AS Total,
            SUM(CASE WHEN a.DeliveryItemStatus = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Missing,
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM StorageTransportOrderItem WHERE DeliveryNumber = a.DeliveryNumber AND DeliveryItemNumber = a.DeliveryItemNumber)  As StoCount
           FROM DeliveryItem a
           INNER JOIN TransportItem b on a.DeliveryNumber = b.DeliveryNumber
           INNER JOIN Material c on a.MaterialNumber = c.MaterialNumber
           INNER JOIN Transport d on b.TransportNumber = d.TransportNumber
           WHERE a.StorageLocationNumber IS NOT NULL
                AND a.Deleted <> 1
                AND c.CommissioningArea LIKE @commissioningArea 
                AND d.TransportStatus < 70
           GROUP BY b.TransportNumber
```

but when I always get the error message:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_CalculateTransportProgress,
>   Line 41 Column 'DeliveryItem.DeliveryNumber' is invalid in the select
>   list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or
>   the GROUP BY clause. Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Procedure
>   sp_CalculateTransportProgress, Line 41 Column
>   'DeliveryItem.DeliveryItemNumber' is invalid in the select list
>   because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the
>   GROUP BY clause.

My goal is to add this single column (StoCount) to the cursor without modifying the query too much.
Is that possible?

Comment: Have you tried adding StoCount to the GROUP BY?

Comment: StoCount is no database column name, only a name of a column of the cursor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could move the correlated subquery to a `cross apply`

```
SELECT b.TransportNumber, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN a.DeliveryItemStatus = 'C' OR a.DeliveryItemStatus = 'V' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Completed, 
        COUNT(*) AS Total,
        SUM(CASE WHEN a.DeliveryItemStatus = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Missing,
        MAX(e.Freq) AS StoCount
FROM DeliveryItem a
INNER JOIN TransportItem b on a.DeliveryNumber = b.DeliveryNumber
INNER JOIN Material c on a.MaterialNumber = c.MaterialNumber
INNER JOIN Transport d on b.TransportNumber = d.TransportNumber
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT COUNT(*) freq FROM StorageTransportOrderItem  s
    WHERE s.DeliveryNumber = a.DeliveryNumber AND s.DeliveryItemNumber = a.DeliveryItemNumber
) e
WHERE a.StorageLocationNumber IS NOT NULL
  AND a.Deleted <> 1
  AND c.CommissioningArea LIKE @commissioningArea 
  AND d.TransportStatus < 70
GROUP BY b.TransportNumber
```

Edit by xsl:

I had to modify the query a bit, so that it returned the correct results for my database:

```
        SELECT b.TransportNumber, 
                SUM(CASE WHEN a.DeliveryItemStatus = 'C' OR a.DeliveryItemStatus = 'V' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Completed, 
                COUNT(*) AS Total,
                SUM(CASE WHEN a.DeliveryItemStatus = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Missing,
                SUM(e.Freq) AS StoCount
        FROM DeliveryItem a
        INNER JOIN TransportItem b on a.DeliveryNumber = b.DeliveryNumber
        INNER JOIN Material c on a.MaterialNumber = c.MaterialNumber
        INNER JOIN Transport d on b.TransportNumber = d.TransportNumber
        CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT COUNT(1) freq FROM StorageTransportOrderItem s
            WHERE 
                s.DeliveryNumber = a.DeliveryNumber
                AND s.DeliveryItemNumber = a.DeliveryItemNumber
                AND s.MaterialNumber = a.MaterialNumber
        ) e
        WHERE a.StorageLocationNumber IS NOT NULL
          AND a.Deleted <> 1
          AND c.CommissioningArea LIKE @commissioningArea 
          AND d.TransportStatus < 70
        GROUP BY b.TransportNumber
```

Comment: Wow, that is amazing and saved my day. I have to check if the results are correct, but it looks pretty good